# Merge 2 queries into 1 query

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 queries which i need to merge into 1, they are getting data from the same tables but difference is minor between them

I need to merge this queries:

```
select sum(balance_delta) as "Not Rental"
from h_driver_balance
where
    changed between (select current_date - interval '1 days') and (select current_date) 
and driver_balance_id in (select id 
                          from driver 
                          where driver_ds_account_id = 16 
                          and callsign not like '0%') 
and comment like 'Refill on the terminal 1%';
```

and

```
select sum(balance_delta) as "Rental"
from h_driver_balance
where
    changed between (select current_date - interval '1 days') and (select current_date) 
and driver_balance_id in (select id 
                          from driver 
                          where driver_ds_account_id = 16 
                          and callsign like '0%') 
and comment like 'Refill on the terminal 1%';
```

I've tried to do WITH and UNION, but I seem not to understand something.

Comment: Do you want two rows or two columns after you merged the statements?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `between (select current_date - interval '1 days') and (select current_date) ` can be simplified to `between current_date - 1 and current_date`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i need to merge for two columns which i can name, because it's gonna be used in report

Comment: Is `driver.id` the primary key of the `driver` table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes i can, it's related to driver who refilled his balance.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes driver.id is primary key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204555/discussion-between-lotarc-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two columns, you can do that with a single query and conditional aggregation:

```sql
select sum(b.balance_delta) filter (where d.callsign not like '0%') as "Not Rental",
       sum(b.balance_delta) filter (where d.callsign like '0%') as "Rental"
from h_driver_balance b
  join driver d on d.id = b.driver_balance_id
where b.changed between current_date - interval '1 days' and current_date
  and d.driver_ds_account_id = 16 
  and b.comment like 'Refill on the terminal 1%';
```